Add shortcode for product name and tag in product description using Post Snippets
I'm looking for to add a shortcode that will show product name in product description, and another one that will show product tag.
Also how to unlock shortcodes in product description.
I'm using Woocommerce. And Post Snippets to create shortcodes.
Don't know what codes to use.
